# What is the actual size of point cloud from a kinect

Tags: kinect, openni-camera, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all.

As far as I know a kinect provides 640x480x3 size of 2D image data (widthxheightxRGB) and
640x480x(sizeof a point in 3D).

Is there anyone who knows the actual size of a point cloud?

640x480x4x3 ? widthxheightx(float)x(x,y,z) ?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9922/what-is-the-actual-size-of-point-cloud-from-a-kinect./) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-05-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The data payload is 640 x 480 x 8 x sizeof(float) bytes = **9830400 bytes**

Plus some bytes for auxiliary information like origin, timestamp etc.

A good way to check out the **bandwidth required for transmission** is `rostopic bw`

```
$ rostopic bw /camera/rgb/points
subscribed to [/camera/rgb/points]
(...)
average: 295.37MB/s
    mean: 9.83MB min: 9.83MB max: 9.83MB window: 100
```

**To find the size in memory consider the following analysis:**

I store them as pcl::pointcloud. The data for one point is described in [this header file](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pcl/html/point__types_8hpp_source.html), although it is somewhat cryptic. PointXYZRGB is described as follows:

```
00204 struct PointXYZRGB
00205 {
00206   PCL_ADD_POINT4D;  // (...)
00207   union
00208   {
00209     struct
00210     {
00211       float rgb;
00212     };
00213     float data_c[4];
00214   };
00215   EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
00216 } EIGEN_ALIGN16;
```

PCL_ADD_POINT4D and the union below will add 4 floats each. While that is overkill memorywise, it is required to benefit from some cpu optimizations. Therefore for a pcl::pointcloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> from the kinect, you store ***640 x 480 x 8 x sizeof(float)*** bytes.

I wonder why rgb is in a separate struct though. Does anybody know this.

For a PointCloud2 you can look at the message with `rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/rgb/points| less`.
The interesting parts are:

```
height: 480
width: 640
point_step: 32
```

Therefore, also here you have 640 x 480 x 32, where 32 is 8 x sizeof(float)

**Optimization Hack**

A colleague of mine modified the openni_camera driver and rgbdslam to communicate the color value via the unused forth dimension of the pointXYZ. **This essentially cuts the required memory to half the size.** It is a little hackish, but if anyone wants the patch, you are welcome to contact me. Keep in mind though, that linear algebra operations with Eigen might be affected by the color value or overwrite it. Haven't experienced that yet though.
The bandwidth reduction shown by `rostopic bw`

```
average: 148.35MB/s
        mean: 4.92MB min: 4.92MB max: 4.92MB window: 100
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably worth pointing out that the Kinect itself does *not* output point clouds, but rather a depth map. That is, you can think of the Kinect output as being a 640x480 array (that's 307,200 entries) where each entry contains the Z-axis value of the point in the world corresponding to that entry. IIRC this Z-value is encoded with 11 bits but stored in 16 bits, so the size of the (depth, excluding colour) dataset coming off of the sensor is 307,200*2 = 614,400 bytes. At 30 fps that's about 18 MB/sec. However, when you project these depth values to 3D to get 3 floats per entry in the array the size of the dataset of course expands greatly.

The point is, depending on your application, you might not need *all* of the depth information projected to 3D coordinates, at the full 30 fps. I don't know what your application is but here's a made-up example. Say you want to grab 3d models of faces that are within the Kinect's view. Your first stage is to use the (RGB) camera data to detect bounding boxes of faces. Then you want to find out the 3D points that are associated with those bounding boxes. This means that you really only want to project the depth data that is associated with the bounding boxes, not all of it.

BTW with the openni_camera driver there is a way to do this; in the current (Diamondback) driver you can set the `use_indices` parameter, and then publish `pcl/PointIndices` messages to `camera/depth/indices`. The pointclouds output on `camera/depth/points` will then only contain projected points corresponding to the indices you asked for (i.e. the ones that correspond to the bounding boxes in the example above). This is what I did for my quadrotor kinect demo, to cut down the amount of 3D data to a reasonable level so that the onboard CPU could handle the calculations at the full 30 Hz.

The newer openni_camera driver (openni_camera_unstable) looks like it provides more flexibility still -- you can subscribe directly to the raw depth information and do whatever you want with it.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) on 2011-10-04**:
Patrick, I am trying to use the use_indices method to cut the bandwidth, but cannot get it to work. Would you be so kind as to have a look at my question at http://answers.ros.org/question/2343/how-to-use_indices-with-kinectasus ? Much appreciated!

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-05-11**:
Yes, the Atom board. Full resolution of depth data -- RGB data not used at all. Used about 10% of the overall point cloud (at least in the initial working implementation where mask was just a rectangle, later was more complex and I'd have to look into how many points actually get used). HTH, Cheers.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-05-11**:
Were you using the AscTec Atom board in the Kinect altitude hold experiment (could you please provide some more info regarding the onboard computer used when not)? How much data did you have to leave out in order to achieve real-time operation and what resolution of depth / RGB data were you using?